# Can I use amqplib in the browser?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rabbitmq, amqp, node-amqp

I am an AMQP/RabbitMQ newbie, and relative Node.js newbie.  Can I use the  amqplib NPM library client-side?

I'd like to be able to push messages direct to RabbitMQ from my Angular app.  I have used Browserify to modularise a lot of my client-side code.  I am now starting to experiment with RabbitMQ and would like to push messages direct from the browser to cloud-based queues over the amqp protocol.

I have installed amqplib via NPM and written/pasted the following module:

```
var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');

var push = function(){
    console.log('This is the CORE queue.pusher push function being triggered');

    var connString = 'amqp://username:pwd@blabla.rmq.cloudamqp.com/username';

    amqp.connect(connString, function(err, conn) {

        if (err){
            console.log("core queue.pusher push error %s", err);
        }else {
            conn.createChannel(function (err, ch) {
                var q = 'FatController';
                var msg = 'Hello World!';

                ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: false});
                // Note: on Node 6 Buffer.from(msg) should be used
                ch.sendToQueue(q, new Buffer(msg));
                console.log(" [x] Sent %s", msg);
            });

            setTimeout(function () {
                conn.close();
                process.exit(0)
            }, 500);
        }
    });

};

module.exports = {push:push};
```

When I try running this I get the following error:

```
bundle.js:32074 TypeError: QS.unescape is not a function
    at openFrames (bundle.js:9551)
    at connect (bundle.js:9629)
    at Object.connect (bundle.js:7959)
    at Object.push (bundle.js:7652)
    at controller.pushQueueEntry (bundle.js:7805)
    at fn (eval at compile (bundle.js:32907), <anonymous>:4:184)
    at callback (bundle.js:44543)
    at Scope.$eval (bundle.js:35710)
    at Scope.$apply (bundle.js:35810)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (bundle.js:44548)
    at defaultHandlerWrapper (bundle.js:21283)
    at HTMLInputElement.eventHandler (bundle.js:21271)
```

Am I barking up the wrong tree here?  Will amqplib only run in a 'proper' node environment?

As a secondary question, what is the best way to determine whether a particular NPM package will run in the browser environment?  It seems to me that some NPM packages will run in the browser, and some won't - what is the best way to be confident about this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Will amqplib only run in a 'proper' node environment?

Yes, I'm afraid so.

> As a secondary question, what is the best way to determine whether a particular NPM package will run in the browser environment? It seems to me that some NPM packages will run in the browser, and some won't - what is the best way to be confident about this?

It's not always clear if a package can run in a browser or not, so you have to apply some heuristics:

- Does a package require setting up "plain" TCP connections (meaning connections that aren't used for the usual web-based protocols like HTTP(S) or WebSockets)? If so, it's probably a server-side package.
- Does a package require reading arbitrary files? If so, again, probably server-side.
- Does a package provide, or depend on, native Node.js addons? If so, it's a server-side package.
- As an extension of these: does it use `fs`, `net`, `cluster`, `http`, `https`, `tls`, `dns`, `os`, `tty` or `dgram`? Most likely server-side.

Packages that can be used client-side typically say so in their documentation, so if it isn't specifically mentioned, there's a good chance that it's only server-side.

I hadn't used Browserify in a while, so I had to check, but it looks like it doesn't warn you if the code you pass it depends on server-side modules. It will create a bundle that at some point will just fail with an error, much like what you're running in to.

[Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), another commonly used bundler, has a concept of *deployment targets*. By default, it will target browsers, and when you try to bundle a project that depends on server-side modules like the ones I mentioned above, you will get an error:

```
$ webpack -p bundle.js
Hash: 767ace79fc17abef93e8
Version: webpack 2.6.1
Time: 3983ms
    Asset    Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
bundle.js  308 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
   [0] <SNIP>

ERROR in ./~/amqplib/lib/connect.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/private/tmp/node_modules/amqplib/lib'
 @ ./~/amqplib/lib/connect.js 152:11-25
 @ ./~/amqplib/channel_api.js
 @ ./test.js

ERROR in ./~/amqplib/lib/connect.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in '/private/tmp/node_modules/amqplib/lib'
 @ ./~/amqplib/lib/connect.js 155:11-25
 @ ./~/amqplib/channel_api.js
 @ ./test.js
```

As you can see, my test file uses `amqplib`, which depends on `net` and `tls`, which are both not available in the browser environment. So if you're unsure about whether or not a package can be used in a browser, Webpack provides you with a safety net.

Comment: Very helpful and comprehensive answer Robert, thanks very much :)